# Is there a generic behavior of Spectral Form Factor for Integrable models?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, chaos-theory, integrable-systems

The spectral form factor is defined as (usually taken at $\beta = 0$ by definition along with disorder average)

\begin{equation}\label{eq:SFF1}
   g(\beta,t) =  \left| \frac{Z(\beta,t)}{Z(\beta)}\right|^2 = \frac{1}{Z(\beta)^2} \sum_{m,n} e^{-\beta (E_m+E_n)}e^{i(E_m - E_n)t}
\end{equation}

It is often used as a diagnosis of quantum chaos. The dip-ramp-plateau behavior is shown to be common in GOE, GUE random matrix and, therefore, a sign of quantum chaos [[1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-023-04692-y)]. There are only a few literature that discuss the SFF of integrable models and the universal nature of SFF in such models [[2]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP01(2023)153). In ref. [[2]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP01(2023)153) For example, they didn't find such a behavior in the integrable model, but it did emerge when they took the disorder average. I want to ask if there's a universal behavior of SFF in the integrable systems or model that follows Poisson-level statistics distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The SFF's linear ramp regime is a fingerprint of chaos because it results from level repulsion. The eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian (or unitary evolution operator) in a chaotic (quantum) system repel one another due to interactions.

This is also captured by the $r$ ratio for level statistics, which is the average ratio between consecutive energy differences $r = \min(\Delta_i,\Delta_{i+1})/\max(\Delta_i,\Delta_{i+1})$, where $\Delta_{i} = E_i - E_{i-1}$. We find $r \sim 0.38$ for Poisson-distributed eigenvalues and $r \sim 0.55$ or something for Gaussian-distributed eigenvalues.

As you say, integrable systems have Poisson statistics, since they have an extensive number of conserved quantities; as a result, the eigenvalues basically all belong to independent "charge" sectors, and thus do not repel one another. So, we should not expect to see $K(t) \sim t$ either!

So what does the SFF look like for a nonchaotic system? Well, there shouldn't be a linear ramp regime!

For small systems integrable systems, you might see only a dip and plateau, and no linear regime. This happens if you plot the SFF for a single qubit, which looks like $K(t) = 2 + e^{-t^2} (2 - 4t^2)$ when $H$ is drawn from the Gaussian unitary ensemble (after averaging). This doesn't really have a linear regime.

For *perfectly uncorrelated systems*, you will see $K(t) = \mathcal{D}$ for $t > 0$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is the Hilbert space dimension (note that $K(0) = \mathcal{D}^2$, by definition). On the other hand, for a chaotic system, we only have $K(t) = \mathcal{D}$ for $t > \mathcal{D}$, for reasons I explain [in this answer on SFFs](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/481786/what-is-the-spectral-form-factor/743596#743596). In fact, if you consider a model of noninteracting qubits hopping on a lattice with random $Z$-field disorder, averaging the SFF over disorder gives exactly $K(t)= \mathcal{D}$ for $t >0$. This model is not integrable, of course, but an Anderson insulator.

More generally, as you note in your question and I also note in [my previous answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/481786/what-is-the-spectral-form-factor/743596#743596), systems with conservation laws (or systems that are not maximally chaotic) only realize the linear ramp regime after some time $t \geq t^{\,}_{\rm th}$, which is the "Thouless time" (see [this paper by John Chalker](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.07736)). This is the time at which chaos sets in, and it follows the "dip" regime you identified. In general, a system fails to be chaotic if $t^{\,}_{\rm th} > \mathcal{D}$.

So basically, any integrable system either (1) clearly doesn't have a linear ramp regime or (2) analytical calculations will predict the ramp regime starts after $t=\mathcal{D}$, so it does not actually exist. In practice, **the prediction for integrable systems is roughly** $K(0)=\mathcal{D}^2$ and $K(t>0) \sim \mathcal{D}$, with no significant functional dependence on $t$ (though some fluctuations and dip-like behavior may manifest).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You said in your last paragraph that (2) the ramp regime starts after $t =\mathcal{D}$, so it doesn't actually exist. I don't follow that. Why did you say that it doesn't exist?

Comment: Secondly, I'm studying a Transverse Field Ising Model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse-field_Ising_model) with g = 1 & h = 0. The model is known to be integrable. However, when I did a numerical calculation of SFF for this model, I found the dip-ramp-plate behavior. The behavior may not be very evident, but when taking a sample average, the behavior is easily seen. Do you have any comments on this? (Note that while doing the calculation, I removed few symmetries such as parity & Z-reflection but the level statistics are not as chaotic (in fact due to free model,it's around 0.24).

Comment: I don't think the case (2) I mentioned happens for integrable (or free) models, but I think I once encountered a constrained or localized model where doing some perturbation theory predicted that the ramp regime started after $t \sim \mathcal{D}$, and plots for actual systems show no ramp. I maybe should remove this comment, and included it just in case.

Comment: Regarding the TFIM, if you don't restrict to any sectors, then you should see a dip followed by noise with no ramp. If you restrict to enough symmetry sectors in some integral models, you may see repulsion. But from what I remember, anything below the Poisson value of r=0.38 is an artifact of degeneracies (not extensive conserved quantities). I think restricting to a sector with fixed $\mathbb{Z}_2$ "charge" and definite (total) momentum should be enough to fix this? I'd be surprised to see a ramp there without adding disorder, is that what you mean by sample average?

Comment: In the Integrable TFIM model, I'm taking parity & Z-reflection sector (I'm taking fixing momentum since I'm working with open boundary conditions). With this setting, I'm getting level statistics to be lower than 0.38 (around 0.24 if I remember correctly). I'm further taking disorder average over J (adding a small number of orders 10**-4). I should mention that the ramp is visible even without a disorder average, although it becomes more prominent with it. I can add a few plots if like.

Comment: If you add disorder, the model is no longer integrable. It's still a "free-fermion model" in the sense that it is bilinear in fermion operators. But it is not integrable anymore. While there are still an extensive number of conserved quantities, they are no longer quasilocal, so you can expect to see chaotic behavior.

Comment: I see. So, for integrable cases, it doesn't make sense to add disorder or doing disorder average. But why do the level statistics remain the same even after adding disorder? (note that I'm adding a very small disorder since otherwise, energy levels are degenerate and level statistics ratio can't be found).

Comment: My intuition here is that it's because it's still a "free" system, meaning that you can still identify free-fermion modes (they're just not translation invariant), and each of those is independently conserved. As a result, the many energy eigenvalues are independent. Also, disorder leads to more independent eigenvalues...it's interactions that cause them to repel! So an interacting integrable model with disorder would be more likely to get more level repulsion due to symmetry removal (from disorder), but for the free case, you only lose translation.

Comment: Thanks! Can you let me know your affiliation and name, I would like to give you credit for the discussion.

Comment: I don't know that that's necessary lol (I'm always happy to discuss such things!) but I'm Aaron Friedman at CU Boulder.